# How to allocate qt classes in dll

Tags: c++, qt, dll, qwidget, qlibrary

I am trying to implement plugin system for my project. I am using Qt 5.15 and static Qt libraries. I have a plugin dll that implements my custom interface. I am using QLibrary to load dll library without any problem. However, while I am trying to create QWidget in dll, it says “QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget”. I could not find any solution. Can you help me?

Comment: The error is pretty clear: you "Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget". Have you did that?

Comment: Yes, I have a QApplication. Inside this application, I am calling dll. After I call dll function, this problem occurs. I think QApplication is not passed to dll functions.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html#static-plugins Basically, you need to either build your plugins statically, or build Qt dynamically